# How do I use camel endpoints to manage files?

Tags: apache-camel, citrus-framework

I have an application that reads files in a folder, changes its content and writes it back in another folder. I'm trying to add integration tests with Citrus to write a file in the first folder with some content and check the altered content in the second folder once the application modified it.

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57910464/file-endpoint-for-citrus-framework) where the reply says to use a Camel route but I'm fairly new with those concepts and do not know where to really start...

I don't really understand the `<camelContext>` tag and how it works. I wrote what is following so far, which is where I just try to write in a file:

```xml
<citrus-camel:endpoint id="inputCamelEndpoint" camel-contxt="inputCamelContext" endpoint-uri="file://C:/HL7/source/?fileName=test.hl7"/>

<camelContext id="inputCamelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="inputRoute">
        <to uri="file://C:/HL7/source/?fileName=test.hl7"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>

<send endpoint="inputCamelEndpoint">
    <message type="plaintext">
        <data>Hello!</data>
    </message>
</send>
```

What should I write for `<from uri="">`?
And also, is the xmlns attribut of `camelContext` broken? I have [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZMyG.png).

I really hope someone can give me some details about all of this, I'm quite lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!
I haven't heard of Citrus framework before encountering this question but I know a wee bit of Camel and shall try to help you here with a personalized Camel 101, to get you going.

First things first

- A `CamelContext` is like a runtime environment for Apache Camel integration framework. Think of it as something like Spring `ApplicationContext`. All the stuff that you create with Camel lives in the context.
- A Camel [Route](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/routes.html) is a processing pipeline. It takes input from something(`http`,`jms`,`file`... [almost everything under the sun](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/)), applies zero or more steps of processing on it and produces an output to something (`console`,`disk`, `http`,..you name it).
  If we consider a simple route, it is likely to have two `Endpoints`. A
  `Consumer` endpoint that consumes `Messages`, one or more `Processor` components that inspect and process inbound messages and a `Producer` endpoint that sends the final messages somewhere (as in store to disk, print on a testminal, HTTP post to a server ...)

In your case, as far as I understand, you need a `Route` that can receive a message from Citrus framework and store it to disk, so that your System Under Test can process this file. To interpret this use case as a route definition, in Camel's XML DSL.

```xml
<camelContext id="inputCamelContext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
            http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
  <route id="inputRoute">
    <from uri="direct:citrusConsumer" />
    <to uri="file://C:/HL7/source/?fileName=test.hl7" />
  </route>
<camelContext/>
```

`direct:` URI represents a synchronous `Consumer` endpoint [[Docs on `direct` component]](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/direct-component.html). What this example route does is, take whatever input message arriving at the consumer(`direct:direct:citrusConsumer`) and write it to a file, with name `test.hl7`   in the directory `C:/HL7/source/`. If you want to get fancy here, please read additional options for the [File](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html) component. Citrus-Camel [integration docs](https://citrusframework.org/reference/html/#camel-endpoint) also show usage of a `direct:` component named `direct:news`. Once the `Route` in the example code above `Route` is ready, Citrus can send a message to `direct:citrusConsumer` to talk to Camel.

Reusing your sample code, the integration would be like the snippet below (Note the change to endpoint-uri)

```xml
<citrus-camel:endpoint id="inputCamelEndpoint" camel-contxt="inputCamelContext" endpoint-uri="direct:citrusConsumer"/>
```

I hope this helps you to get ahead.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It helped me find what I was doing wrong. I was writing the endpoint and the camel context into the test file itself and not in the Citrus Spring configuration file... I also put the schemaLocation links you provided into the `<beans>` tag and the `camelContext` was recognized!